# How to use custom CodeMirror modes using react-codemirror2

Tags: reactjs, codemirror, codemirror-modes, react-codemirror

How do you use custom *CodeMirror* modes when using *react-codemirror2*? Both `CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode` and `CodeMirror.defineMode` are undefined after I import as follows:

```
import {UnControlled as CodeMirror} from "react-codemirror2";
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
```

Context: In my react project I'd like to use *CodeMirror* and define my own input language which matches against some regex's and then highlights them to indicate the user has entered them correctly. I also want line numbers, no wrapping, monospace fonts, therefore a code editor seems close to what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options to use custom modes using react-codemirror2.

1. Use the [`defineMode`](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2#props) prop and pass in the mode and its function:

```js
import { UnControlled as CodeMirror } from "react-codemirror2";
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';

<CodeMirror
  options={{
    lineNumbers: true,
    defineMode: {
      name: 'yourMode',
      fn: yourModeFunction
    },
    ...

  }}
  ...
/>;
```

2. Separately import CodeMirror and define your mode before the control is rendered:

```js
import { UnControlled as CodeMirrorControl } from "react-codemirror2";
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror';

CodeMirror.defineMode('yourMode', yourModeFunction);

<CodeMirrorControl
  options={{
    lineNumbers: true,
    ...
    mode: 'yourMode',
  }}
  ...
/>;
```